# How to get username from one mysql table by the ID stored in another?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a favorites system for the logged in user. They will be favoriting songs.
I have 3 tables: `users`, `songs`, `Favorites`.
users contains `users_id, users_uid` (the username i need). songs contain `song_id`, `song_track`(the name of song). favorites contains `users_id`, `song_id`.
They reference each other.  `users` and `favorites` contain the same correct corresponding `users_id` in them.

I already have an insert query on my website that lets users favorite and puts their `users_id`, and the corresponding song they favorited `song_id` into the `Favorites` table.

I want to display on the webpage all the `users_uid`(usernames) who have favorited said `song_id`
So far, I have only gotten as far as displaying all the `users_id` who have favorited said `song_id`

```
class Test extends Dbh {

public function getUsersStmt($songidfav) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Favorites WHERE song_id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$songidfav]);
    $names = $stmt->fetchall();

    foreach ($names as $name) {
      echo $name['users_id'] . '<br>';
    }
  }
```

in the index page I use "1"(which is the corresponding `song_id` they have stored in their `favorites`)

```
    $testObj = new Test();
    $testObj->getUsersStmt("1");
```

This only shows me all the `users_id` that favorited...
How do I create the relationship between the tables in a select query to display their usernames `users_uid` instead of their `users_id` in the outcome? php oop pdo for now please.

Comment: Have you looked into `JOIN` yet?

Comment: Learn about INNER JOIN in SQL (regardless of whether you use PHP or any other language to execute the query)

Comment: Although not your sample data exactly, check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91b15a/3

Comment: @ChrisHaas I got your sqlfiddle to work with my sample data but only if I rename my database to song and not songs like my existing one. My db `songs` insides are named `song_id` and NOT `songs_id` which I think is affecting the way mysql is reading the select before the join when using s.track unless I change `song`... then s.track will work. Is there a way to write s.track in a different way so it gets data from the correct `songs` database i already have linked to `favorites`?

Comment: Unfortunately SQL fiddle is down so I can't share anything. But the names of the objects shouldn't matter, just get the general pattern down `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table` is the basic, and you can alias tables for convenience, such as `SELECT my_alias.* from table my_alias`, which you'll see commonly with joins. Lastly, to join, `SELECT * from favorites f LEFT JOIN users u ON f.users_id = u.users_id LEFT JOIN songs s ON f.song_id = s.song_id`. For this, completely ignore PHP, too, and try working only in a SQL tool such as PhpMyAdmin or similar.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need in your for each loop to do another request. This request is in the table of users and it need to get the content of user by his user id like `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_id = ?"` and then you can get the username

Comment: how would the select query inside of my for each loop look like? im struggling to get it working... now not even getting the original list of `users_id` when I tried to add the addition you mentioned.